# layout_centerVertical in Nested Relative Layout causing incorrect positioning of textviews on Android P

Tags: android, android-layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
        android:background="@color/orange7">

        <TextView
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/title" />

        <TextView
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:text="@string/subtitle" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a layout file with nested relative layouts. On android P devices only, the `textviews` in inner relative layout are incorrectly placed.
This layout file is used for an activity with `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` as a theme.

[image]

On Other android devices(non Android P devices), its getting arranged properly.

[image]

What must be the reason for this mis-arrangement on android P? Changing outer layout to Linear layout solves issue. Why is it so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConstraintLayout instead of the RelativeLayout as the container for the TextViews' to achieve the effect you desire across all API versions.

Note the usage of ConstraintLayout as the container of text views, and the usage of attributes like `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/<your_id>"`.

To know more about constraint layout, please refer [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout (Google Documentation)](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
        android:background="@color/orange7">

        <TextView
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/subtitle"
            android:text="@string/title" />

        <TextView
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
            android:text="@string/subtitle" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It will solve my problem. I am trying to identify root cause of this issue.